# The blur filter does not work in the browser firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I use the blur filter in my react application, in google browser or in microsoft edge everything works fine, but when I decided to test it in mozilla firefox I found out that it doesn't work there, I checked [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur()) and didn't find anything special, maybe you have ideas?

```
<div style={{backdropFilter: `blur(${someValue}px)`}}
     ...
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, backdrop filter is not supported by default in firefox. https://caniuse.com/css-backdrop-filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backdrop-filter property is not enabled by default in Firefox. It is supported in newer versions, but it is hidden behind a flag, see [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter#browser_compatibility) to see that flag.

However you can probably achieve the same effect, using the more supported [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) css property. The difference is that filter applies the effect to the element itself, while backdrop-filter applies it to the area behind the element.